# R Shiny Server cannot find files containing spaces

Tags: html, r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to use a browser to access files contained in the `www` subfolder served by a Shiny server that I am running in an ad-hoc way. This works when the file names do not contain characters that need to be escaped but if a file contains something like a space in the name, I get a 404 not found error.

Here is the minimal example code.

```
#app.R
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      plot(cars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I create a www folder below where I have saved the app.R file and in this folder I put two files. One called `works.txt` and the other called `not works.txt` with a space in the name.

Run the app like so to ensure I can access it remotely.

```
runApp(host="0.0.0.0", port = 8182)
```

Using a browser to visit the page - let's say at 10.8.0.1 - I find

`http://10.8.0.1:8182/works.txt`  - works and I can see whatever is in the file.

`http://10.8.0.1:8182/not works.txt`  - doesn't work and returns a 404 error.

Am I doing something stupid? Is there any additional logging I can enable to see what is happening? Is there a setting I don't know about to change the behaviour of the Web server that Shiny uses?

I should add that if the file is named with `%20` in the name then it works.

I have included sessionInfo() below

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.13.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-6  R6_2.1.2          rsconnect_0.4.2.1 htmltools_0.3.5   tools_3.2.2       Rcpp_0.12.4       jsonlite_0.9.19  
 [8] digest_0.6.9      xtable_1.8-2      Cairo_1.5-9       httpuv_1.3.3      mime_0.4
```

I can also monitor the traffic using Wireshark and I see that a request to the file with a space in the name is being correctly escaped by the browser so the Web server is being asked to serve `not%20works`. A file with this name does not exist so I suspect this leads to the error. I'm guessing that the Web server should reverse the url encoding before searching for the local file. Of course, this is only a theory and I can't prove it.

My workaround is to rename all files locally using URLdecode and URLencode as required.

Comment: It is generally not recommended to have space in file names. Is there a reason you need to allow spaces in file names?

Comment: I receive a large number of files with odd names so I don't have any choice. I can workaround by renaming but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: As this could be implementation specific you should post the output from  `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I played around with it for a bit and it looks like when I type in the %20 the browser is not interpreting the %20 as it access files with %20 in their name. Which makes me think that a programmatic retrieval would work since you could control the encoding.

Comment: Just re-tested this and it now works so clearly there's been a change made to `shiny`.